# Retrieve the top 10 from the database

Tags: php, mysql

I have this query but I just want to return the top 10 based on the num_guess. I don't know the format of the query. I don't know where to put LIMIT or TOP. Please help!

```
"SELECT user,num_guess FROM game JOIN difficulty USING (difficulty_no) WHERE difficulty_no=2 ORDER BY num_guess ASC "
```

Answer (score 3):

use `limit 10`

something like this

```
"SELECT user,num_guess FROM game 
 JOIN difficulty USING (difficulty_no) 
 WHERE difficulty_no=2 ORDER BY num_guess ASC limit 10"
```

Answer (score 1):

With two arguments, the first argument specifies the offset of the first row to return, and the second specifies the maximum number of rows to return. The offset of the initial row is 0 (not 1):

```
-- SELECT * FROM tbl LIMIT 5,10; # Retrieve rows 6-15

 SELECT user,num_guess FROM game 
 JOIN difficulty USING (difficulty_no) 
 WHERE difficulty_no=2 ORDER BY num_guess ASC limit 0, 10
```

you can go with `LIMIT 10` here in this context

Answer (score 0):

Just add `LIMIT 10` at the end of your query.

Answer (score 0):

use `LIMIT 10`

```
"SELECT user,num_guess FROM game 
    JOIN difficulty USING (difficulty_no) 
        WHERE difficulty_no=2 ORDER BY num_guess ASC LIMIT 10"
```

for more information check this http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en//limit-optimization.html

Answer (score 0):

Yes the limit would work here.

```
SELECT user,num_guess FROM game 
    JOIN difficulty USING (difficulty_no) 
        WHERE difficulty_no=2 ORDER BY num_guess ASC LIMIT 10;
```

To view more just increase the limit.